# Why is $\displaystyle{W(-i\pi)}$ not equal to $\displaystyle{i\pi}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, lambert-w

The product log/Lambert's W $W(x)$ is defined as the inverse function of $\displaystyle{f(z)=ze^z}$. Since  $-i\pi=e^{i\pi}\cdot i\pi$, why is $W(-i\pi)$ not equal to $i\pi$? My calculator+WolframAlpha instead give a number around $0.925+0.836i$.

Comment: The function $f(z) = ze^z$ is not injective (even over the reals), so the inverse is multi-valued. It seems that $-i\pi$ is not in the range of whatever branch of $W$ your calculator and Wolfram Alpha is using.

Comment: [Try using a different branch](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=productLog%281%2C-pi*i%29)

Comment: I see. Thank you two!